# What's the difference between Yaw and Attitude in Quad Rotor

Tags: imu

I have a big miss conception between Yaw and attitude ?

Isn't both represent "how far is the quad from earth ?"

Also if you could post how to calculate them from IMU (gyro +accele + magent )

Comment: No.  Yaw is lateral rotation.  This picture should explain it.  https://developer.valvesoftware.com/w/images/7/7e/Roll_pitch_yaw.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing two words that are spelled almost identically:

Altitude:  (with an L) is the distance from the vehicle to the earth.  It is given in terms of meters.

Attitude:  (with a T) refers to the orientation of the vehicle with respect to a reference frame.  It is usually given in terms of roll, pitch, and yaw, which are all essentially angles of rotation along the x, y, or z axis.

Comment: Great !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!